# SharedPreferences in ArraryAdapter

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to use a value stored in a shared preference to help style a listview and when I use this code it comes back the default value;

```
    SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences("Level", 0);
    mCounter = pref.getInt("Level", 3);
```

This is the code I used to store the preference:

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("com.komodostudios.asllessons", MODE_PRIVATE);
         pref.edit().putInt("Level", 1).commit();
```

Comment: Please put code here. how you store data in preafrence??..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
getSharedPreferences(String name, int mode)
```

where `name` is the name of the *preferences file*

`getInt (String key, int defValue)`

where `key` is the actual *preference key*

Do you have named your preferences and the key both `"Level"`? If not that is the problem.

This should work:

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("com.komodostudios.asllessons", MODE_PRIVATE);
mCounter = pref.getInt("Level", 3);
```

Comment: Ya, I got them mixed up. Thanks for the help. I can't accept your answer yet but I will when I can.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the preferences have been changed from their default settings?  When using the `SharedPreferences.Editor` you must remember to call `commit()` to save your changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
    SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("com.komodostudios.asllessons", MODE_PRIVATE);

    mCounter = pref.getInt("Level", 3);
```

You have to do above code..

Use below code to store & get value from prefrance. this is best way to do this.

For store data:

```
    pref = PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    editPref = pref.edit();
    editPref.putBoolean("logedin", true);
    editPref.commit();
```

For Get Data:

```
pref = PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
editPref.getBoolean("logedin", false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set same shared preference name when you want to get the value.Like here you want to get your value in  "Level" preference but put in different shared preference " com.komodostudios.asllessons".
So that you get the default value for "Level"
Code will be like that:
To store:
`SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("com.komodostudios.asllessons", MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor editPreference=pref .edit();
editPreference.putInt("Level",2);
editPreference.commit();`
To retrieve:
`SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("com.komodostudios.asllessons", MODE_PRIVATE);
int mCounter = pref.getInt("Level",1);`